# Scala - how to access an object from a class?

Tags: scala, collections

I want to create a Map with information about sales in one class (object) and that use it in another class `ProcessSales` - iterate over the Map keys and use values. I have already written logic creating a Map in an object `SalesData`.

However since I've started learning Scala not long ago I'm not sure if it is a good approach to implement the logic in an object.

What will be the correct way to access the Map from another class?
Should the Map be created in an object or in a separate class? Or maybe it's better to create an object in the `ProcessSales` class that will be using it?

Could you share best practices and examples?

```
object SalesData {

  val stream : InputStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/sales.csv")
  val salesIterator: Iterator[String] = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(stream).getLines

  def getSales(salesData: Iterator[String]): Map[Int, String] = {
    salesData
      .map(_.split(","))
      .map(line => (line(0).toInt, line(1)))
      .toMap
  }

  val salesMap: Map[Int, String] = getSales(salesIterator)
}
```

Comment: `import SalesData.salesMap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted flexibility to "mix in" this map you could put the map and getSales() into a new trait.

If, on the other hand, you wanted to insure one and only one factory method existed to create the map, you could put getSales() into a companion object, which has to have the same name as your class and defined in the same source file. For example,

```
object ProcessSales { 

 def getSales():Map[Int,String] =  {...}

}
```

Remember that methods in a companion object are analogous to static methods in Java.

It is also possible to put the map instance itself into the companion object, if you want the map to be a singleton--one map instance per many instances of ProcessSales.

Or, if you want 1 such map per each instance of ProcessSales, you would make it a field within the ProcessSales class.

Or, if you wanted the map to be available to all members of a class hierarchy under ProcessSales, you could make ProcessSales an abstract class. But regarding use of an abstract class, remember that use of a trait affords greater flexibility in case you are not certain that all subclasses in the hierarchy will need the map.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you want to use it. Scala is more functional oriented. So for the best practice, you could define getSalesData in an object and in another object you could pass the parameters and call the def getSalesData.

For example,

```
import packaganame.SalesData._;

Object Check {

   val stream : InputStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/sales.csv");
   val salesIterator: Iterator[String] = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(stream).getLines;

   val salesMap = getSales(salesIterator);

}
```